# macos Mojave beta - problem with image thumbnails

Tags: image, caching, thumbnails, macos-mojave

Since I've upgraded to Mojave I keep having issues with image thumbnails. I simply can't see a thumbnails and what is instead is a bland placeholder. Is there any way to clear thumbnails cache, or solve this problem in any other way?

What I've found is somewhere in here works for a few hours, and then the issue happened again.

```
sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store; sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \; ; sleep 3; sudo touch /Applications/* ; killall Dock; killall Finder
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6d4j.png)

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any fix for it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that many are not addressing properly and Apple is ignoring. Try this it worked for me.

Open the Terminal application (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)

Type `qlmanage -r` and hit enter

Type `qlmanage -r cache` and hit enter

Close Terminal and restart your system

This should force QuickLook to reload the generator lists and reset the disk cache.

Comment: It is Sketch V51.

This issue has been resolved with the release of Sketch v52 update.
Just install the update and restart the mac or just delete Sketch and restart.